# Какие предустановленные шрифты можно использовать на ios в коммерческой программе?

Tags: qt, ios, шрифты, qml, лицензирование

Есть коммерческая программа для ios на qt/qml. Какие предустановленные в ios шрифты можно использовать для оформления графического интерфейса? (Qt по-умолчанию подставляет "Helvetica Neue". Заказчик смотрит в сторону "San Francisco".)

Comment: А почему собственно не все, раз уж они уже установлены?

Comment: Это тоже вопрос. Если шрифт установлен (пусть предустановлен), можно ли его использовать для оформления своей программы? Для ios в особенности.

Comment: Я всегда считал, что да, если ты его не распространяешь.

Answer (score 0):

К примеру любой из перечисленных вот здесь: 
https://fonts.google.com/

Они все open source. И их можно использовать, мы на проекте используем к примеру вот этот:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro